# Opencart missing orders

Tags: opencart, secure-trading

I have managed to successfully set up Securetrading extension in opencart. However, all orders through ST are going into "missing orders" opencart.

I have double checked and the payments are being processed (both in test and live mode) and emails are being sent by ST. However, the orders always go into missing orders.

Please can anyone advise

Comment: Please Show some code.

Comment: Not sure what code you need to see. Please clarify?

Comment: I have spoken to Secure trading and they have said that there is a 404 error. The destination page for the payment notification doesn't exist.

I have set it as http://nameofyourshop.com/shop/index.php?route=payment/securetrading_pp/ipn

as opencart is installed in the /shop domain of my site...

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Opencart 2 then the URL should be http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?route=extension/payment/securetrading_pp/ipn